# How to solve a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc, error-handling, stack-trace

I got an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running my program!?
Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/framework/XMLParser
abc.def.presentation.controllers.UnixServerJobController.handleRequestInternal(UnixServerJobController.java:64)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Here is the code for those who concern

```
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception{
    try{
        String jobName = request.getParameter("JobName");
        jobName.concat(".xml");
        String config = request.getParameter("Config");
        File file = new File(config + "/"+jobName);
        ConfigFile jobConfig = new ConfigFile(file);
        SchdJobCaller jobCaller = getJobCaller();
        jobCaller.runJobs(jobConfig);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just passing an url like this abc.com/def.jsp?JobName=name1&Config=config1 to be handled by the controller in Spring Web MVC!

This is what I found when googling around!

> If you are working in J2EE environment than visibility of Class among multiple Classloaders can also cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, see examples and scenario section for detailed discussion.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz28CQRODWN

This could be the root of the problem, but how to solve the visibility of Class to multiple Classloaders!??

This is the first time I got an error like this!
Is there any advice for me?

Thanks

Comment: One simple thing to do is to put a dummy reference to org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser somewhere an "outer layer" of your code, to make sure it's being resolved satisfactorily.  In fact, do a `self.getClassLoader().loadClass()` with the name and monitor for ClassNotFoundException.  If you get ClassNotFoundException then the class is missing from the classpath.  If you get NoClassDefFoundError then there's a mismatch of some sort between your jar files.  If you get neither, but still get the NoClassDefFoundError later, then you do indeed likely have a problem with multiple class loaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find a JAR containing the Apache Xerces XML parser and put it in your CLASSPATH.

Looks like the investxa controllers package wants to use Xerces.  Personally, I don't think that's a good idea.  The Java JDK has had DOM and SAX parsers built in for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using maven? Gradle? Ant?

If maven, just add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <!-- or whatever version you want -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per JavaDoc for NoClassDefFoundError,

```
/**
* Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a <code>ClassLoader</code> instance
* tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call
* or as part of creating a new instance using the <code>new</code> expression)
* and no definition of the class could be found. 
 * <p>
* The searched-for class definition existed when the currently 
 * executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be 
 * found.
*/
```

I suppose the xerces jar existed during compilation but somehow missing during the runtime. If you are dealing with maven then probably your dependency scope is set to compile. You have to set it to runtime to resolve this issue.